# aws java sdk not returning all folders

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Running

```
$ aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/myfolder/subfolder/monitor/
```

and it is returning all the files I expect.  I have permissions and credentials set up correctly.  Then I have written some java code:

```
public class S3Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    AWSCredentials credentials = null;
    try {
        credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider().getCredentials();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AmazonClientException(
                "Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. " +
                "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct " +
                "location (~/.aws/credentials), and is in valid format.",
                e);
    }

    AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
    try {

        ObjectListing objectListing = s3.listObjects(new ListObjectsRequest()
                    .withBucketName("mybucket"));
                        for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
                System.out.println(objectSummary.getKey());
                        }

    } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
        System.out.println("Caught an AmazonServiceException, which means your request made it "
                + "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response for some reason.");
        System.out.println("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
        System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
        System.out.println("AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode());
        System.out.println("Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType());
        System.out.println("Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());
    } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
        System.out.println("Caught an AmazonClientException, which means the client encountered "
                + "a serious internal problem while trying to communicate with S3, "
                + "such as not being able to access the network.");
        System.out.println("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
    }

}
```

The code is printing out things in mybucket/myfolder/subfolder, but nothing in monitor (and is missing other subdirectories).  I am not seeing any errors.  How can I diagnose why I am not seeing more of the files.  I clearly have permissions to the folders and credentials are working.  Any suggestions are helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: You're going to have to provide specifics, showing the output from the command line and your program, at least enough to show the difference where it's not behaving as you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but maybe all of the results just don't fit into one response. See if [ObjectListing#getNextMarker](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectListing.html#getNextMarker%28%29) is not null.